# Why do I get different browser behaviour when attempting to reach bitcoin.stackexchange.com and the alias of its IP in /etc/hosts?

Tags: dns, hosts

I haven't found any browser that supports aliases defined in `/etc/hosts` even when single terms (without having to prepend in the browser with `http://`) are not interpreted as search terms for the default search engine (the case with [badwolf browser](https://hacktivis.me/projects/badwolf)).
Aliases work when prepended with http://, e.g.
`http://bse` but having to type `http://`defeats the purpuse of using them.

Cloudflare does not allow to access bitcoin.stackexchange.com via an alias, defined as
172.64.144.30   bitcoin.stackexchange.com bse

```
Error 1003 Ray ID: 85750e9fc9b65e4d • 2024-02-18 08:56:29 UTC
Direct IP access not allowed
What happened?
You've requested an IP address that is part of the Cloudflare network. A valid Host header must be supplied to reach the desired website.
```

When I attempt to reach `bitcoin.stackexchange.com` I do not get any error from Cloudflare.

1. Am I sending a host header when attempting to reach `bitcoin.stackexchange.com` from a desktop PC with `172.64.144.30    bitcoin.stackexchange.com bse` appended to `/etc/hosts`?
2. Why do I get different browser behaviour when attempting to reach `http://bse` and `bitcoin.stackexchange.com` in the browser?
3. Are there any settings in browsers such as Brave, Firefox (`about:config` ?), Chromium that I could apply to
   use my aliases seamlessly?

Other than in `/etc/hosts` my DNS queries are resolved by by the home router as shown by
the content of my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
search home 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

The research I did is `man hosts`. The hypothetical purpose of appending `172.64.144.30 bitcoin.stackexchange.com bse` to `/etc/hosts` is limiting the number of certain DNS queries (that may make my profiling seem too radical and hence result in targeted surveillence) to the dns server of my router. I am aware of the possibility of reverse-DNS-lookups but let this be outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, your browser well send a Host header, and in the case of HTTPS access, additonally use SNI, to tell the server which site it wants to access. This is of course nothing unusual - a single server can serve any number of websites on any number of hosts, so it needs to know which one you're trying to access. The IP simply isn't enough for a lot of web servers these days.
2. Because of the above, a server may choose to serve you a default website or no website at all if it isn't configured to serve the host you're trying to access on it.
3. In Firefox, you can assign keywords to bookmarks so that just accessing the keyword will you take you to the bookmarked link. You don't have to use `http://<keyword>`, but just the bare keyword. Right-click on any bookmark and edit it, and the resulting dialog box will have a field for entering a keyword.